# Flash Video player buffer issue and large video files

Tags: php, actionscript, flash, flash-video

We have developed flash video player which needs to playe large videos (at least 500 MB videos).

We have some issues in the player right now.

1. I am playing a 100 MB + video, it start playing and say it is buffering upto 50% of that video. Then I am closing that page. If I take that video again, it starts downloading from beginning. It never resume downloading from where it buffered previous time. But for small video files, this is looking ok. Is there any size limit a video player can buffer? or any other issues. Please share your thoughts
2. Is there any better way to play large videos (more than 500 MB). Any other protocol or any other settings in flash player? Please give your valid suggestions here also...

Answer (score 1):

If *streaming video* is out of the question (eg servers are expensive) you may also try a **modified-progressive** download. The server basically takes the browser request and cuts a specific version of the video which it then sends to the user's browser. I know there are extensions of this for various popular servers. Infact, this is very similar (if not , the same) as what [youtube](http://youtube.com) uses.

Some references to gawk at:

- [Mod H264 Streaming for Apache](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Apache-Version2)
- [FlowPlayer Pseudostreaming](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html)
- [Serving up a video file using php](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/servers-and-streaming/17872/serving-up-a-file-mp4-flv-etc-using-php)